# Set Category Axis Label Title for Kendo Angular Pie Chart

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I am new to Kendo UI and trying to implement Pie Chart. I am not able to set category Axis Label title for the chart. I am not sure whether this is applicable to the pie chart or not.

Plunker for Code : https://plnkr.co/edit/9WGlMwwvbqaFFytoP2Do?p=preview

I have tried some workaround but it doesn't seem to be helpful. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**app.component.ts---***

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AxisLabelsPosition } from '@progress/kendo-angular-charts';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <kendo-chart [seriesColors]="['orange', 'red']">
      <kendo-chart-legend position="bottom"></kendo-chart-legend>
      <kendo-chart-title position="top" text="Pie Chart Title \n testing "></kendo-chart-title>

      <kendo-chart-series>
        <kendo-chart-series-item type="pie" [data]="pieData" field="value"
          categoryField="category"  [title]="{text:'testing'}" text = "testing gjkdfgjkhd">
        </kendo-chart-series-item>
      </kendo-chart-series>




      <kendo-chart-category-axis [title]="{'text':'testingLabe'}">
            <kendo-chart-category-axis-item >
                <kendo-chart-category-axis-item-labels rotation="auto"> 
                </kendo-chart-category-axis-item-labels>
            </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>

        </kendo-chart-category-axis>

        <kendo-chart-value-axis>
            <kendo-chart-value-axis-item  [axisCrossingValue]="[0, -1000]">
                <kendo-chart-value-axis-item-labels>
                </kendo-chart-value-axis-item-labels>
            </kendo-chart-value-axis-item>
        </kendo-chart-value-axis>

        // <kendo-chart-value-axis>
        //   <kendo-chart-value-axis-item >
        //       <kendo-chart-value-axis-item-labels [content]="ReturningString">
        //     </kendo-chart-value-axis-item-labels>
        //   </kendo-chart-value-axis-item>
        // </kendo-chart-value-axis>


    </kendo-chart>
  `
})
export export class AppComponent {
   public categoryLabelsPosition: AxisLabelsPosition = 'onAxis';
   public valueLabelsPosition: AxisLabelsPosition = 'start';
  public pieData: any = [
    { category: 'Eaten', value: 0.42 },
    { category: 'Not eaten', value: 0.58 }
  ]

  ReturningString(e){
    console.log(e);
    return 'testinglabeld'
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @amit can you please share the workaround you have done.

Comment: I don't think that the pie chart has axes. Where are you trying to render the title?

Comment: @SiliconSoul I am trying to render just below the title. As of now, I have separated the title with a line break. I was also thinking the same that pie chart doesn't have an axis. Is there any way I can show the category axis title just above the pie chart. thanks

Comment: Don't think so, but it seems that you can use the pane title: https://plnkr.co/edit/CH7ajJ8e75FTbgGtDcKo?p=preview